# Get current file name from a url using javascript/jquery when only folder path is known

Tags: javascript, jquery, filepath, pathname

I am trying to get the current filename from the url using:

```
$currentFile = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();
```

This works fine if the full path is something like:

```
http://www.yoursite.com/folder/index.php
```

It will return index.php, index.cfm, index.html etc.

But when the url is http://www.yoursite.com/folder/

I cannot retrieve the current filename, is this possible via js or jquery?

Comment: No because the default index file is a setting within the webserver. You can make an assumption and just say it's index.html if you're loading a folder...

Comment: That URL has no filename to get. Could you explain why you are trying to this?

Comment: Yes, I am using jquery to show/hide elements within a particular folder structure /contact but not for the index.php file, or only for the index.php file for example.

Comment: if you NEED to know, you can just try fetching HEADs on all the default document names, in order of probability: index.html, index.htm, index.php, default.aspx, default.asp, etc. the first one that doesn't 404 is the right url.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only have the path in the URL, then you cannot get the filename from it - not using jQuery, not using any other client-side method.  This is because only the server that sends this file knows what this file is.  Specifically, in the web server configuration, there's a directive, which indicates what filename to search for if only the directory name is specified.  For example, in apache this can be

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php home.htm
```

This tells the server that for requests with only a directory name the server will attempt to serve file `index.html` from that directory; if it doesn't exist, then `index.php`; if that also doesn't exist then `home.htm`.  If that one also doesn't exist, then the behaviour depends on other configuration options.  Other web server software has similar configuration options.

Hence, when you send a request like http://www.yoursite.com/folder/ to a server, only that server will know what file is actually used.